# How can I reinstall the Android S8 device drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, android

I am having problems with my Samsung S8 today.  When I plug in the phone into my PC I see this:

[image]

I have tried plugging it in over 100 times and it worked a few random times - the other 98 times I got the error above.  So far I have tried:

1) Plug in two other USB devices into my PC.  They both work.

2) Plug the Android phone into my Windows tablet and Mac - they both work every time (with the same cable used on my PC where the problem occurs).

Therefore there has to be an issue with the drivers on my Windows PC.  How can I reinstall the drivers? I have tried downloading this: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows.  However it creates a sub folder called USB drivers with lots of sub folders like: 01_Simmental, 02_Siberian, 03_Swallowtail.  I was hoping that I would be able to go here and find the drivers: https://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/.  Hwever, the S8 does not appear in the drop down box and the search facility does not appear to work!

**Update**

I have reinstalled Windows 10 and this has made no difference.

Here is what I see when I plug in my device:

> [image]

When I unplug my device then unknown device disappears.

harrymc suggested reinstalling the drivers using this link: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows.  I have run the exe and it has created the following folders:

[image]

Which folder contains my drivers?  I am hoping that what I need to do now is:

```
1) Open Device Manager
2) Right click on unknown device (see screenshot for unknown device) and select update driver.
3) Select Browse
4) Select Let me pick from a list of available drivers
5) Select Have Disk
6) Browse to the driver file
```

However, to follow step 6 I need to know were the driver file is.

There is an option to select a folder where the drivers are stored by right clicking on 'unknown device' and selecting update driver as shown below:

[image]

However, when I click next I see this:[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99846/discussion-on-question-by-w0051977-how-can-i-reinstall-the-android-s8-device-dri).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get my Samsung phone working again with my PC I have to disable the following USB Controller in device manager: intel(R) ICH10 family USB enhanced host controller - 3A3A.  Uninstalling it does not work.